# How to simulate tor in a close network?

Tags: proxy, node, research

I'm interested in setting up a simulated tor network on a closed network. I'd like to setup multiple VMs as tor relays and somehow have tor on another VM create a circuit based on the list of tor nodes available in the closed network. I'm not entirely sure how to go about it. I looked at experimentor but it seems like its been abandoned. I don't know if chutney will let me do such thing and if it does, I don't know how to even after reading the README on their git repo.
If anyone knows how to do this, please let me know. Most of the questions that asked about doing a similar thing are about 8 years old. So I can't find a solution that's somewhat recent (2 years old). Thank you!

Comment: Do you need them to be in separate VMs? If so, I don't think there are any tools to do this and you will probably need to set it up manually. Chutney will let you launch the relays/clients on a single computer, but you can use it as a guide to set up your VMs. You may also want to look into Shadow, which is another popular Tor experimentation tool.

Comment: The idea is to get a different ip address for the exit node. So if there is a way to achieve that with chutney, I'd love to know. I don't mind doing the manual work if I can get everything working with multiple VMs. I know I need an authority directory and point tor nodes to that authority directory server. I just don't know how to setup an authority directory server.

Comment: Chutney won't be able to do that without modifications. I would try starting a Tor network with Chutney, copying any Chutney-generated files (torrc, keys, etc) into your VMs, tweaking the torrc files manually to use the correct IP addresses for your VMs, and then start each tor process manually.

Comment: So I copied the ./network/basic file and modified to simply create one authoritative directory server. I then ran ./chutney start networks/authoritative and it seems to work, but I don't know how to specify an IP address and port to bind so I can point tor clients to connect my new authoritative directory.

Comment: I think tor will bind on all network interfaces, so you shouldn't need to specify that. The ports that the authority binds on will be in the torrc file that chutney generates. You can modify those if needed.

Comment: @Steve, so I'm looking at the basic-min network template in chutney and I'm confused as to why there are no guard relay and middle relay. Are the authority relays acting as guard and middle relays?

Comment: Yes, the authorities also relay data. If you look at the consensus on the real network, you'll see that the authorities advertise only a small amount of bandwidth so that they are not used very often for regular circuits.